# "Cannot redeclare i18n_variable_set()"

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have made multilingual site. When we redirect users to another domain, I see the following error:

> [Sun Feb 02 13:03:40 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.80] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare i18n_variable_set() (previously declared in /var/www/html/UNI01JO2012031/sites/all/modules/contrib/i18n/i18n_variable/i18n_variable.module:116) in /var/www/html/UNI01JO2012031/sites/all/modules/i18n/i18n.module on line 894

Please note I am not changing any configuration.

Comment: The error message is quite clear. Have you checked that in line 894 in `i18n.module` there us no declaration of `i18n_variable_set()`?

Comment: no exist  line 894 in i18n.module

Comment: You said: "when we redirect the site to anther domain". What do you mean by that? Did you transfer the sites' code to a different server?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bugreport that should be posted in appropriate issue queue, not here.

Comment: How are you installing modules?  Can you edit the question to include the first 20 lines of /var/www/html/UNI01JO2012031/sites/all/modules/i18n/i18n.module?  I don't think this is a bug, I think you accidentlally overwrote the i18n module with i18n_variable.

Answer (score 5):

The issue here appears to be that you have installed the same module in two directories:

```
sites/all/modules/contrib/i18n
```

and

```
sites/all/modules/i18n
```

and drupal is picking them both up.  If this is the case, I would disable the module, uninstall it, delete one of the directories above, and then re-enable the module.  That should clear this up.

If you can't access your site's admin UI at all, then you will have to go in and remove one of the directories directly; I would suggest removing `sites/all/modules/i18n` as the other directory appears to be being searched first.

ADDITION:  From some line number searching, the Drupal 6 version of `i18n.module` declares `i18n_variable_set()` from lines 881 to 894 and the Drupal 7 version doesn't even get that long--ending at line 610.  This coupled with the fact that the `i18n_variable` submodule isn't even included with the Drupal 6 version has me thinking you have a sorts of module mish mash going on here.

ADDITION 2:

I just installed the Drupal 7 i18n module on a clean install in:

```
sites/all/modules/i18n
```

and enabled it and the i18n variable module.  ALL good.

I then copied the Drupal 6 i18n module's code into:

```
sites/all/modules/contrib/i18n
```

and....

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare i18n_variable_set() (previously declared in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/d7lrfm/sites/all/modules/i18n/i18n_variable/i18n_variable.module:116) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/d7lrfm/sites/all/modules/contrib/i18n/i18n.module on line 894

so, I would check to see if the same thing is happening on your site and if so, remove the errant Drupal 6 version.  A quick check of the `.info` files will show you what core version of Drupal they are for.  (And, oops, yes, here I put the Drupal 6 version in `sites/all/modules/contrib/i18n` and the Drupal 7 one in `sites/all/modules/i18n` which appears to be opposite of what's happening on your site, but I tried to be as similar as possible :)